# Construct3 Splash Screen For HTML5

Tags: splash-screen, construct-3

How to change default splash screen in construct3 HTML5.
which show like [image]

and also in console.log it show bellow message
"Made with Construct 3, the game and app creator :: https://www.construct.net"
how to remove it

Comment: Have you got a license?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a license.

Second, select your project root folder (on right, called Box Size for my project).

[image]

Lastly, select Loader Style and update as you'd like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The splash screen is hidden in the `c3runtime.js` file after you export your game in the form of [base 64 strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

I made a [tool](https://masterpose.itch.io/mp-c2-hacker) to replace the images and colors but to my knowledge only works for **Construct 2**.